List of polychords
can anyone give a list of polychords thinking in grades so I don't depend on any specific tonality?. Or guide me to any book that shows them in this way?.
For example:
If I play a mayor triad on the bVII grade of a minor chord I am playing a min11 chord, if I'm not mistaken.
I'm looking for something like this because it'll make it easier for me to remember them this way.
           bVII
 Xmin11 ►  ----
           Xmin

Don't know if i'm explaining it clearly, since I don't get CHATGPT to create the list properly :(
It tends to fail on the grades and refer to the grade of the overlapping chord instead of the base chord, no matter how many times I try to explain it XD.
Thanks in advance.
By the way this is what GPT is telling me (sorry it's in spanish), and as you see some of the grades are wrong.
Acorde X9(13) → Superpongo Acorde maj7 en su grado bVII
Acorde X13 → Superpongo Acorde 7 en su grado II
Acorde Xmaj13(#11) → Superpongo Acorde 7 en su grado VI
Acorde X7(13) → Superpongo Acorde maj7 en su grado bVII
Acorde X11 → Superpongo Acorde 7 en su grado II
Acorde X13(#11) → Superpongo Acorde maj7 en su grado IV
Acorde X9(#11) → Superpongo Acorde maj7 en su grado IV
Acorde X7(9,13) → Superpongo Acorde m7 en su grado VI
Acorde Xmaj13(#11) → Superpongo Acorde 7 en su grado V
Acorde X9(11) → Superpongo Acorde m7 en su grado V

A polychord can be anything. That is, the list would be infinite, loosely speaking.  I feel your question needs to be more specific about what you’re looking for.

ok thanks for your comment. I thought it would be a less broad term.
I'll try to rethink my question to be more specific about what I'm looking for.
Should I erase the question?.

For me something's lost in the translation. What's the grade of a chord?

oh sorry, I've just looked for a better name, and I guess I should have said degree instead of grade?

I think the term polychord is typically used for chords which could NOT be easily notated with common chord symbol, so NOT the examples you provide. To me it seems more like you're asking how to find triads and simple chords within more complex ones. But what's the purpose? Finding patterns on the instrument? Also, how would you approach enharmonics, e.g. would you consider Db triad to be part of E7/13/b9 chord (requiring enharmonic substitution G#=Ab)

My goal was to easily play more complex chords with extensions on the piano.
Because I thought it would be much easier to think "Dmin triad on the left hand, C triad on the right hand" than to think the whole Dmin11 chord

For those curious, I think a translation of the ChatGPT output (and explanation of where this question is coming from) would be, for instance: "X9(13) chord → Superimpose a maj7 chord on top of the bVII [degree]."

(A mi no es perfectamente claro que significa "en su grado." Aparece que traduccia a "degree," pero los conceptos de "scale degree" y de "tonic function" no son mismos. Y a mi aparece como un modo estraño para pensar de estas acordes; los conceptos de "7" o "9" o "11" son independente de los de funccion tonico (I, IV, V). A mi aparece demasiado complicado combinarlos así.)

(It's not perfectly clear to me what "scale degree" means. It appears to translate to "degree," but the concepts of "scale degree" and "tonic function" are not the same. And it seems to me like a strange way to think about these chords; the concepts of "7" or "9" or "11" are independent of the concepts of tonic function (I, IV, V). To me it seems overly complicated to combine them like that.)

7, 9, 11 etc. could be better thought of as extensions of major, minor, diminished, and augmented. Just as, in the key of C major, the I, IV, and V are all "major chords"—because of the distances between their notes—so they could each generate dominant 7ths, or augmented 9ths, or diminished 11ths, etc., and the best way of understanding them is by the distances between the notes.


...If I play a mayor triad on the bVII grade of a minor chord I am playing a min11 chord

I think by "grade" you mean "chord root." Also, when you say "a minor chord" I think you are implying "the tonic chord" relative to the bVII chord.
So, you have triad i superimposed with triad bVII, which includes scale degrees ^1 ^3 ^5 ^7 ^9 ^11, and altogether is an eleventh chord.
As pointed out in comments, if such triad superimpositions result in diatonic chords, you probably would not call them polychords, but instead just use their diatonic names/symbols: i11 or in C it is Cm11.
I suppose you might use some kind of polychord labeling like i + bVII to suggest that the chord be voiced as two complete, root position triads. There is a type of polychord notation that stacks the two chords vertical with a horizontal line between them. I can't type and example, but visually you can see it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polychord
If you start with a tonic chord base, and then rotate to just the right starting point of the scale for the second chord to go above, you get...

...the interested thing to me is how every other chord combination involves the ^4 scale degree and creates some kind of eleventh chord. You might abstract this to three categories:

diatonic triad, seventh, and ninth chords
add6
chords involving the eleventh

I'm not sure if there is an immediate practical application to this, but in my mind it boils down to this. If you don't think in terms of diatonic chords up to the ninth using their normal names, but instead superimpose diatonic triads, about half of those combination result in some type of eleventh chord.
That seems significant to me, because eleventh chords are dissonant and unstable in the context of tertian harmony. I think that is why a lot of "eleventh chords" or "sus" chords, "quartal" harmonies exclude the choral third (ex. G7sus4.) They are either not bona fide tertian eleventh chords or simply sidestep the dissonance issue by omitting the third. Another way to put it is this. If the eleventh is present, it is a strong enough factor to override the details of other chord extension intervals.
The other potential application is to dispense with your idea for a large chart of chord combinations and think more abstractly of three general categories for superimposed chords. Otherwise, the literal combinations of diatonic triads are seven base triads superimposed with each of the remaining six triads 7 x 6 for 42 combinations. (A few combinations can be eliminated by transposition - ii + IV = iii + V = vi + I but you still end up with a long list.) 30 to 40 such combinations in probably less practical that 3 abstract categories.

...Because I thought it would be much easier to think "Dmin triad on the left hand, C triad on the right hand" than to think the whole Dmin11 chord

I understand your point, but I think you should also consider that when reading a symbol like Dm11 the thought process of execution can be along the lines of "root D, with default 7th for an extended chord, with minimally the 11th" which literally would be...

It is very common to omit tones in extended chords and to not voice them in literal stacks of thirds.
I think it is important for you to think about the chord voicing aspect of this question and make a distinction between extended chords and polychords. The polychord examples I have seen have a distinctive voicing of two simple root position, close voiced triads in separate octaves. (Often the two triads have a chromatic not diatonic relationship, arguably that's the main purpose.) This particular voicing seems important for making the polychord effect clear and distinct from various voicings of extended chords.
A potential pitfall for you is using the "polychord" method to produce diatonic extended chords but with an uncharacteristic voicing for a particular style. A neoclassical work might make an eleventh chord with a literal stack of thirds, but that voicing would be pretty uncharacteristic of common jazz voicings.

Yes, I'd emphasize the voicing aspect: stacked triads, for example, are just one choice of voicing... definitely not in the contemporary jazz idiom, whose internal intervals are more often fourths or tritones.
